# PHP output couple times data from a column

Tags: php, mysql

How do I output data from column, but to be like.. for example - the column is with 40 lines of query results and I want to output only that, that are from 10 to 30 . How to do it with PHP?

Comment: What does your database table look like? Also, if you can provide the code you have so far, that'll give us a better idea about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What do you mean with a column? Are you trying to limit the amount of data you see of your database? Try using SQL's limit for that.

Comment: not clear, can u add more details, code ...

Comment: You mean some sort of pagination? or a LIMIT to the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL, you could use a LIMIT *offset*, *maxrows*:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 9,20;
```

will get you rows 10-30. Note that the *offset* value is 0 based, hence the 9 rather than 10.